# Display NA values with plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Let's say I have a data.table like the following

```
data = data.table(week=c(1,2,3),price=c(2,2.5,1.5),promotion=c("p1",NA,"p2"))
```

week, price, promotion
w1, 2, p1
w2, 2.5, NA
w3, 1.5, p2

I want to display a scattered plot of the price with the different promotion colored.

```
plot_ly(d, x = ~week, y = ~price,color=~promotion)
```

The problem is, the output I have doesn't show the the second observation because of the NA value in the column promotion as shown below.

[image: plotly output]
I want to display all prices including the ones with NA in column "promotion"
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plotly)
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
data = data.frame(week=c(1,2,3),price=c(2,2.5,1.5),promotion=c("p1",NA,"p2"))
data$promotion[is.na(data$promotion)] <- "NA"
plot_ly(data, x = ~week, y = ~price,color=~promotion)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to update the values in the data.table.

Answer (score 2):

Just extending on Pork Chop's solution and your comment under it. Here's a way without changing the values in data.table -

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~week, y = ~price, color= ~replace(promotion, is.na(promotion), "NA"))
```

[image]